# Can't find string in input file

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have a text file, which I am trying to insert a line of code into. Using my linked-lists I believe I can avoid having to take all the data out, sort it, and then make it into a new text file.
What I did was come up with the code below. I set my bools, but still it is not working. I went through debugger and what it seems to be going on is that it is going through the entire list (which is about 10,000 lines) and it is not finding anything to be true, so it does not insert my code.

Why or what is wrong with this code?

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines("Students.txt"));


 using (StreamReader inFile = new StreamReader("Students.txt", true))
 {
    string newLastName = "'Constant";
    string newRecord = "(LIST (LIST 'Constant 'Malachi 'D ) '1234567890 'mdcant@mail.usi.edu 4.000000 )";
    string line;
    string lastName;
    bool insertionPointFound = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count && !insertionPointFound; i++)
    {
        line = lines[i];
        if (line.StartsWith("(LIST (LIST "))
        {
            values = line.Split(" ".ToCharArray());
            lastName = values[2];
            if (newLastName.CompareTo(lastName) < 0)
            {
                lines.Insert(i, newRecord);
                insertionPointFound = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!insertionPointFound)
    {
        lines.Add(newRecord);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just reading the file into memory and not committing it anywhere.

I'm afraid that you're going to have to load and completely re-write the entire file.  Files support appending, but they don't support insertions.

you can write to a file the same way that you read from it

```
string[] lines;
/// instanciate and build `lines`
File.WriteAllLines("path", lines);
```

`WriteAllLines` also takes an `IEnumerable`, so you can past a `List` of string into there if you want.

---

one more issue:  it appears as though you're reading your file twice.  one with `ReadAllLines` and another with your `StreamReader`.

Comment: Eww... yea I was afraid of that... I am going to try and see what I can do with an appending method of writing an entirely new file and then reading the new file. This is an exercise out of a book I bought from a yard sale. Just because it had c# on it I purchased it... starting to think the book is well... not worth the few bucks I gave for it....

Answer (score 2):

There are at least four possible errors.

- The opening of the streamreader is not required, you have already read
  all the lines. (Well not really an error, but...)
- The check for StartsWith can be fooled if you lines starts with blank
  space and you will miss the insertionPoint. (Adding a Trim will remove any problem here)
- In the [CompareTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w.aspx) line you check for < 0 but you should check for == 0. CompareTo returns 0 if the strings are equivalent, however.....
- To check if two string are equals you should avoid using CompareTo as
  explained in MSDN link above but use string.Equals

  ```
  List<string> lines = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines("Students.txt"));
  string newLastName = "'Constant";
  string newRecord = "(LIST (LIST 'Constant 'Malachi 'D ) '1234567890 'mdcant@mail.usi.edu 4.000000 )";
  string line;
  string lastName;
  bool insertionPointFound = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count && !insertionPointFound; i++)
  {
      line = lines[i].Trim();
      if (line.StartsWith("(LIST (LIST "))
      {
          values = line.Split(" ".ToCharArray());
          lastName = values[2];
          if (newLastName.Equals(lastName))
          {
              lines.Insert(i, newRecord);
              insertionPointFound = true;
          }
      }
   }
   if (!insertionPointFound)
       lines.Add(newRecord);
  ```

I don't list as an error the missing write back to the file. Hope that you have just omitted that part of the code. Otherwise it is a very simple problem. 
(However I think that the way in which `CompareTo` is used is probably the main reason of your problem)

**EDIT** Looking at your comment below it seems that the answer from `Sam I Am` is the right one for you. Of course you need to write back the modified array of lines. All the changes are made to an in memory array of lines and nothing is written back to a file if you don't have code that writes a file. However you don't need  new file

```
File.WriteAllLines("Students.txt", lines);
```

Comment: I attempting that.. Still is not working. I am thinking maybe I have to write into a new file? I just would have swore I could use a link list to add something to it, sorted or not... at least add.